# What kind of bonuses does the VIP give?

Tags: sky-force-2014

Yesterday I played Sky Force and for the first time I noticed the acronym VIP underneath a level. Obviously I played this particular level, and came across a special person (the VIP I think), which I picked up, like every other rescueable person. Are there any bonuses associated with this VIP?

[image: Image of Sky Force]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an achievement called ["The Command is in your Debt"](http://tipwikiguide.com/achievements-sky-force-2014-wiki-guide/) (apparently worth 5000xp) for saving 5 of these VIPs - though they are quite rare.